# Difference between * and .* in regular expressions

Tags: regex

What is the difference between the regular expression `*` and the expression `.*` The meaning of `*` is - any character occurring any number of times, and the meaning of `.*` is any character occurring zero or more times. Both essentially mean the same. Can somebody please explain the difference?

Comment: I wasn't much aware about it earlier, but now, I have reviewed previous questions and accepted the most relevant answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `*` is a *quantifier* that modifies the meaning of the **previous** character, group or character class in the regex. On its own it is meaningless. It only carries meaning when combined with what is immediately before it in the regex.

So, `.*` means any character occurring 0 or more times, `a*` means `a` appearing 0 or more times, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions `*` by itself does not mean anything. It *modifies* the expression in front of it. There may be confusion with *wildcards*, where `*` means the same thing as `.*` in regular expressions. In regular expressions `*` by itself or as the first character in an expression is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `X*` is: "X, zero or more times" (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). `*` is only the quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

`.` means any character. `*` means previous character (or group) 0 or more times. So `.*` means any character 0 or more times. That's it

Answer (score 0):

`ab*de` will match `ade`, `abde`, `abbde`, `abbbde`, `abbbbde` and so on.

`ab.*de` will match all above except `ade`.

Comment: The first statement is incorrect, `ab*de` will match `abde` and `abbbbbde` but not `abcde`